# How to transfer mouse focus back while showing a QMenu?

Tags: python, pyside2

I have two buttons and both of the has some hovering effect. The first button has a menu as well, and the problem is, when the first button is clicked and menu appears, the mouse hover doesn't work for the second button at the same time until the menu is closed.

I'm not sure, but I believe it is due to some sort of `focusPolicy`, and I tried to find the solution but I couldn't. I just want to make hovering effect on the buttons of the widget available even while showing the menu.

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()
        self.resize(300, 300)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button 1')
        btn.setStyleSheet('QPushButton::hover{background-color: gray;}')
        layout.addWidget(btn)
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self)
        action = QtWidgets.QAction('buttonAction', menu)
        menu.addAction(action)
        btn.setMenu(menu)
        
        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button 2')
        btn.setStyleSheet('QPushButton::hover{background-color: gray;}')
        layout.addWidget(btn)

        self.setLayout(layout)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
wig = MyWidget()
wig.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Please be noted, instead of stylesheet, I even tried using `evenFilter` changing the colors on `Enter`/`Leave` events and returning `True`/`False values.

Comment: It could *theoretically* be possible, but extremely hard to achieve, possibly impossible to make it in a way that it could be used transparently and easily, while keeping it reliable and not prone to bugs or unexpected behavior. Considering the expected result and the fact that it could probably work very badly and create bugs, it's really not worth the effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL; DR; The behavior you want is not possible.

### Explanation:

Only one window can have the focus and only the widgets that belong to that window can get the focus. In this case, the QMenu lives in a different window that is on top of the original window and that window is the one with the focus and no longer the original window.